# list menu load data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

help me someone 
i want make listmenu load data in mysql...
how to make listmenu data in mysql, 
help me someone 
i want make listmenu load data in mysql...
how to make listmenu data in mysql,

my source from load

product_info_detail.php

```
    <style type="text/css">
.teks_info_produk {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #000000;
}
.teks_harga_produk {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #990000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<?php
include("config.php");
$id_barang = $_GET['id_barang'];
    $query = "select * from barangtbl where id_barang = '".$id_barang."'";
    $hasil = mysql_query($query);
    $temukan = mysql_num_rows($hasil);
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);
    if($temukan==0){
    }else{
?>

<table border=0px cellpadding='10' cellspacing="2" bgcolor="" bordercolor="" align="center">
    <tr>

<td align=center>            
    <div class ="teks_info_produk">
        <?php echo $data['nama']; ?><br><br>
        Size 
        <label>
        <select name="size" size="1" id="size"> **"listmenu make manual coding"**
          <option>36</option>
          <option>37</option>
          <option>38</option>
          <option>39</option>
          <option>40</option>
                </select>
        </select>
        </label>
        <br><br>
        <?php echo $data['warna']; ?><br><br>
    </div>

    <div>
    <img width='200px' height='225px' valign='top' border='1,5' src="produk/<?php echo $data['gambar']; ?>"><br><br>
    </div>      

    <div class ="teks_info_produk">
        <?php echo $data['deskripsi']; ?><br><br>
    </div> 

    <div class ="teks_harga_produk">
        <?php $hargarp = $data['harga'] ?>
        <?php echo "Rp " .number_format($hargarp, 0, ',', '.').",-" ?><br><br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <?php
        echo '
    <a href="produk_beli.php?id_barang='.$data['id_barang'].'"><img src="Gambar/TBeli.jpg"\ title="Beli Sekarang" border="0" width=\"50\" height=\"30\"></a>';
        ?>
    </div>
     <hr />

<?php
    }
?>
</td>    
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And I want a Porsche... What is your problem and what is your question ?

Comment: Can I have a porsche too? I work 40 hours a week and still have no porsche. Help me someone I want a porsche.

Comment: "I want to  ... How to ... Help me ... Please" dont use this ... 
Just TDP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this code will help for you
------------------------------

<?php
include("config.php");
$id_barang = $_GET['id_barang'];
    $query = "select * from barangtbl where id_barang = '".$id_barang."'";
    $hasil = mysql_query($query);
    $temukan = mysql_num_rows($hasil);
?>  
    <table border=0px cellpadding='10' cellspacing="2" bgcolor="" bordercolor="" align="center">
    <tr>

<td align=center>            
<div class="six columns">
              <label>State</label>
                <select name="data" id="data">
                    <option value="">Select Data</option>
                    <?php if($temukan>0){ while($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)) {?>
                    <option value="<?=$data['tbl_column_name']?>">
                    <?=$data['tbl_column_name']?>
                    </option>
                     <? } }?>
                </select>
               </div></td>    
</tr>
</table>
```